My keyboard shortcut doesn't work when I'm on finder because of its default keybindings
I have created a shortcut in my Mac's Quick Actions with a shell script to run, and gave it the keyboard shortcuts option+cmd+t.

It works great in any other app than Finder, where it just does its default action of minimizing or un-miminizing the left pane (instead of executing the script).
Has anyone else encountered this? (it also didn't work on finder with other key combination I have tried.)

See Ask Different - How do I add, change or remove a key command (shortcut) from a menu item?
